# Passing ImageField between 2 django projects

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have 2 django projects which have some common tables.

to be able to access one of these tables from one of the projects, I'm using database routing => Problem solved for the database communication.

But I couldn't figure out how to transfer files between projects.

I tried this :

```
photo = ContentFile(default_db_object.photo.file.read())
distant_db_object.photo.save("test_name.jpeg", photo, save=True)
# Tried to save just in case, even if it's already done above
distant_db_object.save()
```

I also tried the second line of this code with :

```
distant_db_object.photo.save("test_name.jpeg", default_db_object.photo, save=True)
```

- default_db_object : is model object from my current project
- distant_db_object : is model object from my *distant* project

I think I still didn't understood the logic beyond the whole File storage logic in django (yes I've read the docs).

Comment: Do you want to copy the src file to a new one, or simply want both `ImageField`s point to the same file?

Comment: I think that copying the src file to a new destination is much better.
But if having ImageField pointing to the same file is easier, I'll take it.